# How to treat subsamples that differ in respect to the dependent variable prior to any treatment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, group-differences, small-sample

I have conducted an experiment on a sample that consisted of both male and female students to see if a specific emotion influences moral judgment. My research goal didn't involve any hypothesis about the effect of gender, but focused entirely on the effects of emotion induction. 
While analyzing my data I found that female and male participants in the control group differ significantly in moral judgment, i.e. they differ without the independent variable being applied.

My question is how do I treat these groups (males and females) in my further analysis? Do I have to treat them separately, meaning we are talking about two different populations with respect to the variable being researched? Or is it acceptable to continue on with the analysis on females and males together, as planned?

I have to add that both subgroups (males and females) react in the same way (or maybe "direction") to the independent variable, which is also the effect that is predicted by my research hypothesis. While this effect is stat. significant when I have males and females combined, it loses it's "power" on the sub-sample of females alone (and becomes marginal at p = 0,075; it is still significant in the group of males, though). 
A further issue that I have to take into consideration is that while I have a satisfying amount of participants in both the control (N=31) and the experimental group (N=32), having to "dissect" those further would result in quite a small amount of male groups (7 for C group, and 5 for E), which messes up the significance for some other important variables (that I don't really need to get into right now).

All in all, I would like to treat these two groups together, but am hesitant to do so since they do differ in one (somewhat) important aspect. In writing the research I will of course dedicate a section to explain this difference, but I would like to circumvent the nag of having to analyse everything separately for males and females, especially since gender differences weren't an issue I planned on exploring (and since this would take a lot of precious space). This is more of an (unpredicted) side issue that could be explored in further research.

I would like to hear your thoughts about the problem, and any evidence for and against grouping these two together. Thank you!